# eclipse not detecting the changes i made in code

Tags: eclipse, jboss, ejb

I have an old `EJB` project to make changes. I am running this project on my eclipse luna and Jboss 6.x server. so when i try to debug it, any changes i make on my code won't take effect. it will simply run the old codes ( before i made changes).

I search/googled but i am still unable to find the solutions.

what i tried to solve this issues:-

1. Clean the project and build again.
2. Turned on Build automatically
3. switched workspace
4. deleted .metadata files in work space and re run the project.
5. cleaned Jboss server
6. restarted PC and tried to run the project.

when i run the project in debug mode it simply says `source path lookup` as shown in image below. (project runs successfully even when it says source path lookup)

[image]

what might be the other possible reasons that my code changes are not reflecting ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem of hot deployment. Try to clean your deployment folder manually: $JBOSS_DIR/standalone/deployments